# Correct packages to install LAMP on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, php, lamp

I have read some tutorials about install LAMP and I have seen that they install differents packages for MySQL and PHP.

For example to install MySQL:

```
 1. mysql-server
 2. mysql-server libapache2-mod-auth-mysql php5-mysql
 3. mysql-server mysql-client libmysqlclient-dev
 4. mysql-server mysql-client
```

For PHP:

```
 1. php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
 2. php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-cli php5-mysql
 3. libapache2-mod-php5
 4. php5 php-pear
```

Also I noticed that LAMP can be installed with only one command:

```
lamp-server^
```

And also with tasksel:

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

This all very confusing. I have two machines one ubuntu 12.04 and other ubuntu 14.04. How can I know what packages I need to install?

Answer (score 1):

Those tutorials are probably "helping" by having you install multiple things at the same time that they'll be using later; mostly libraries to glue the different technologies together.  So, to install a MySQL server, `mysql-server` is the only package you need, but if you wanted to have Apache authenticate to MySQL you'd want `libapache2-mod-auth-mysql`, and to get PHP talking to MySQL you'd want `php5-mysql`.

`tasksel` installs a pre-set group of packages, and probably has most of what you need, and you can always install the additional library packages later if you need them.